# Defining and plotting a Schechter function: plot problems

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib, astronomy

I'm currently defining a function in python as:

```
def schechter_fit(logM, phi=5.96E-11, log_M0=11.03, alpha=-1.35, e=2.718281828):
    schechter = phi*(10**((alpha+1)*(logM-log_M0)))*(e**(pow(-10,logM-log_M0)))
    return schechter
```

schechter_range = numpy.linspace(10.0, 11.9, 10000)

And then plotting said function as:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero

schechter_range = numpy.linspace(10, 12, 10000)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

ax.plot(schechter_range, schechter_fit(schechter_range), 'k')
```

This is the graphical output I am receiving is just a blank plot with no curve plotted. There must be a problem with how I have defined the function, but I can't see the problem. The plot should look something like this:

[image]

I'm new to python functions so perhaps my equation isn't quite right. This is what I am looking to plot and the parameters I am starting with:

[image]

Comment: for your range `(-10)**((stellarM)-11.03))` will get complex eventually... please consider naming your constants (e.g. `phi=5.96E-11; someconst=11.03`) and limiting your brackets to as few as needed (for the above expression i prefer: `pow(-10, stellarM-11.03 )`). no need to put a variable in brackets.

Comment: Please post your questions as an mvce: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've made changes, please comment further if it is not mvce.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I'm not sure why it will get complex. The range and subsequently range on stellarM is between 10 and 12.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I've made a few subsequent changes and I'm also including the parameters I am using for the plot.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist would it be possible to see if you could check eq.(13) in my question against what I have plotted. I just can't see where I have gone wrong. If I have. Would welcome a second opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you describe returns a complex result over most of your input range.  Here I added `+0j` to the input to allow for an imaginary result; if you don't do this you just get a bunch of `nan`s (which mpl doesn't plot).  Here are the plots:

[image]

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero

schechter_range = numpy.linspace(10, 12, 10000)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

def schechter_fit(logM, phi=5.96E-11, log_M0=11.03, alpha=-1.35, e=2.718281828):
    schechter = phi*(10**((alpha+1)*(logM-log_M0)))*(e**(pow(-10,logM-log_M0)))
    return schechter

y = schechter_fit(schechter_range+0j)  # Note the +0j here to allow an imaginary result
ax.plot(schechter_range, y.real, 'b', label="Re Part")
ax.plot(schechter_range, y.imag, 'r', label="Im Part")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Now that you can see why the data is not plotting, and that complex numbers are being generated, and you know physically that you don't want that, it would be reasonable to figure out where these are coming from.  Hopefully, it's obvious that these are originate from `pow(-10,logM-log_M0)`, and from there it's clear that this is assuming the wrong operator precedence: the equation isn't `pow(-10,logM-log_M0)`, but `-pow(10,logM-log_M0)`.  Making this corrections gives (after a log is taken, because I can see the log in the plot in the question):
[image]

I also extended the lower bound from `10` to `8`, so the region of constant slope is clear and it better matches the graph shown in the question.  This is still off by a factor on the y-axis, but I'm guessing that's a factor of (SFR/M*) that's not being applied correctly (it's difficult to know without seeing the context and the full y-axis).

Comment: So this is very puzzling. I know this isn't quite good form but could you see if you could plot the above equation which accompanies my question with the parameters quoted. I must have made a mistake for what you have shown to of happened...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts: I think you can do this debugging as well as me.

Comment: I've been debugging this for perhaps an hour now. I'm going around in circles.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts: I've posted a second figure which resolves the issue of getting a complex result.

Comment: @tom10 Many thanks for solving this for me Tom. However, I'm using import math > math.log(the function) and I'm returning the following error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. How exactly did you convert to the log of the function?

Comment: @tom10 Scrap that Tom, I've got it! numpy.log10 works better and the fit matches my data well. I'm really pleased.

Answer (score 0):

i did amost the same as [tom10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102302/tom10) except that i took the log of your expression directly, which turns the factors into summands and may make things easier to debug.

i did not really test the formula!

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero

def log_schechter_fit(logM, SFR_M=5.96E-11, log_M0=11.03, 
                      alpha=-1.35):
    schechter = numpy.log(SFR_M)
    schechter += (alpha+1)*(logM-log_M0)*numpy.log(10)
    schechter += pow(-10,logM-log_M0)
    return schechter

schechter_range = numpy.linspace(10, 12, 10000)

# for i in range(10,13):
for i in numpy.linspace(10, 11.03, 10):
    print(i, log_schechter_fit(i+0j))

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)
ax.set_xlim([10,12])
y = log_schechter_fit(schechter_range+0j)

ax.plot(schechter_range, y.real, 'b', label="Re Part")
ax.plot(schechter_range, y.imag, 'r', label="Im Part")
ax.legend()
```

and i got:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

again using [tom10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102302/tom10)'s comments on operator precedence and changing the last part in the function:

```
LOG_10 = numpy.log(10)
SFR_M = 5.96E-11
LOG_SFR_M = numpy.log(SFR_M)
def log_schechter_fit(logM, log_SFR_M=LOG_SFR_M, log_M0=11.03, 
                      alpha=-1.35):
    schechter = log_SFR_M
    schechter += (alpha+1)*(logM-log_M0)*LOG_10
    schechter -= pow(10,logM-log_M0)
    return schechter
```

i can reproduce the plot of the accepted answer. the shape of the curve fits but i can not explain the discrepancy to the values compared with the original plot posted in the question...

[image]

Comment: I understand that this is why it is not plotting by not including the `+0j' expression. However, I think the issue lies with my usage of mathematical expressions in python. I would like to have a confirmation that I have correctly expressed the function from (13) from my question. If not, I'll have to re-work it.